# Is there some way to prevent a byobu terminal from timing out?

Tags: byobu

The ssh session in my byobu terminal is timing out from inactivity if left open for long. Is there some way to keep the keep the terminal alive because it prevents me from seeing the output to the screen in long running sessions. I am using byobu on Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like it's actually your SSH session timing out, as Byobu sessions so not time out.

Check the ssh(1) manage, and perhaps look at the options: ServerAliveInterval, ServerAliveCountMax, and ConnectTimeout options which you can set in your ~/.ssh/config.